Add extension in Ubuntu 22:04 to XAMPP
Working on windows (10 or 11) to emulate a server I used MAMP and to add extension it is very simple. In your php.ini file, e.g, if you want to add curl extension uncomment the line
extension = php_curl.dll
If I want develop in environment Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) MAMP does not exist. There is XAMPP.
In this case, how to add extensions? There is the php.ini but in linux are not used .dll but .so files.
Could you help me o suggest a link where these configurations are reported?
PS: The question is not related to the difference between .dll files (dynamic-link-library) and the .so files (shared objects). The topic is how to add extension in an emulated server, to developing a full stack web app, in linux environment.
Minimal reproducible example
Suppose to add the extension curl
On Windows 10/11 go to the php.ini and
from
#extension=php_curl.dll
change in
extension=php_curl.dll
Thanks to Hassan
On Linux (Debian/Ubuntu)
apt install php-ext-curl

Thank you
Obtain help to configure XAMPP on ubuntu22.04

The Linux equivalent of .dll is .so.

curl, along with many other common extensions is included (built in) with PHP when you install XAMPP on Linux, so in order to use it you don't need do anything or make any changes to php.ini. It is bundled into PHP when XAMPP compiles and installs its software.
If there's an extension you need that XAMPP does not include, then you have to follow the Installation instructions for the specific extension you're trying to use. Typically this involves building and installing a PECL module.
The install process for any other module not included with XAMPP will be similar. Most PHP extensions can be installed using the PECL modules and will follow the similar pattern of downloading it, installing requirements, running phpize, configuring the module, making it, installing it to PHP's extension directory, and finally enabling it in php.ini.
Example Module Installation
For example, say you wanted to install the sodium extension which is normally bundled with PHP >= 7.2, but does not seem to be included with XAMPP PHP 8.2, here is how you'd do it.
You'll need to read the module documentation's "Requirements" and "Installation" instructions to make sure any prerequisite libraries are installed before installing the PHP module.
For sodium, the libsodium library needs to be installed first:
Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt install libsodium-dev
RHEL/Rocky: sudo dnf install libsodium-devel
Once the required libraries are installed, follow the PHP module's install instructions:
Installation using PECL says to download the module from https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium, so first download and extract the files:
cd /tmp
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/libsodium-2.0.23.tgz
tar zxf libsodium-2.0.23.tgz
cd libsodium-2.0.23

Next, the standard process for building and installing a PECL module is to phpize it first:
/opt/lampp/bin/phpize

phpize output looks like:
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20220829
Zend Module Api No:      20220829
Zend Extension Api No:   420220829

Next, configure the module. Note: We have to specify the path to php-config if it isn't in PATH:
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config

Configure should succeed as long as all the prerequisites are installed.
Then, make and install the module:
make
sudo make install

Installing the module tells you where it puts the module so PHP can find it.
Installing shared extensions:     /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/

If you look in XAMPP's PHP extension directory, you'll see the new sodium.so PHP module there.
Finally, to activate it, edit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini and add the line extension=sodium.so to the end of the extensions list.
To test that it's working:
/opt/lampp/bin/php -i | grep sodium

If the module installed successfully, you should see info about it in the php info output:
sodium
sodium support => enabled
sodium compiled version => 2.0.23
libsodium headers version => 1.0.18
libsodium library version => 1.0.18

